# Let $G$ be a random variable with $G=G(X,Y)$ where $G(x,y)=3x+y^2$. find $E(G)$

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $G$ be a random variable with $G=G(X,Y)$ where $G(x,y)=3x+y^2$. Find $E(G)$

i know that $E(X)=E(Y)=1$ and $Var(X)=Var(Y)=1/2$

is this enough to answer the question?

Im sure this is'nt too hard but i'm having a mind blank, could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: This is a perfect example of missing context: The question cannot be answered without information about the random variables $X,Y$. Would you provide further information, please.

Comment: Ah my apologies! I know that X and Y are not independent and $E(X)=1$ and $Var(X)=1/2$

Comment: Maybe you mean that $Var(Y) = 1/2$?

Comment: It is unwise to present both G and G(X,Y) as random variables. Only G(X,Y) is defined on Omega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearity of expectation gives us here: $$\mathbb EG=3\mathbb EX+\mathbb EY^2$$

To find $\mathbb EY^2$ you can make use of: $$\text{Var}Y=\mathbb EY^2-(\mathbb EY)^2$$

Comment: You are welcome. Formally (as @Did remarks) you should say something like: $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $Z:=G(X,Y)$ where $G:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto 3x+y^2$. To be found is $\mathbb EZ$.